# Set width between annotation & bar using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, data-science

I couldn't find any parameter which can set a width between annotation & bar. The numbers are touching on the bars. Can you please let me know how to resolve the issue?
Here is the code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
manufacturer = ['Yamaha', 'TVS', 'Bajaj', 'Hero']
sales = [2000, 1780, 1500, 3000]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 10))
ax.barh(manufacturer, sales, color='orange', edgecolor='blue')

for s in ['top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right']:
    ax.spines[s].set_visible(False)

ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(pad=5)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(pad=10)

ax.grid(b=True, color='grey',
        linestyle='-.', linewidth=0.5,
        alpha=0.2)

ax.invert_yaxis()

for i in ax.patches:
    plt.text(i.get_width() + 0.3, i.get_y() + 0.5,
             str(round((i.get_width()), 2)),
             fontsize=10, fontweight='bold',
             color='grey')

ax.set_title("Demo")
plt.ylabel("Manufacturer")
plt.xlabel("Sales in k")
plt.show()
```

[Here is the bar plot snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxZQh.png)

Comment: It's the number you add to `i.get_width()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was doing mistake by adding a number less than 1.